# How to deploy a website with GitHub pages from a folder other than "docs/"?

Tags: github, github-pages

I am creating a GitHub repository that is a website and has as its entry point the `index.html` file. I would like to put it in a `src/` folder and publish it with GitHub pages. Unfortunately, GitHub offers me either to create a `docs/` folder (which contains the documentation normally), or to place the `index.html` at the root of the project.

How can I deploy the website from a folder other than docs?

Repo link: https://github.com/timotheeMM/snake-game

Comment: I believe it's a setting in GitHub Pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`peaceiris/actions-gh-pages`](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages) github action to deploy a folder of your choice to the `gh-pages` branch. Github will then deploy the contents of this branch.

On your main branch, create a `.github/workflows/web.yml` file with the following content:

```yaml
name: Deploy website

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Deploy
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./src # deploy src folder
```

In the `Pages` tab of your repository settings, set the deploy branch to `gh-pages`:
[image]

Each time you push a commit to the `main` branch, the `gh-pages` branch gets automatically updated with only the contents of the `src` folder:
[image]

Your website will then be available at `https://<username>.github.io/<repo-name>/`