# How to create automatic theme pages

Tags: github, github-pages

How can I launch automatic page generator on GitHub? It says that there is nothing like that any more, but can someone give me an alternative?

I tried checking GitHub Pages but no help. My layout is different from what the pages are saying.

[picture of what my page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3dta.png)

Comment: what are the folder structure under the /doc folder? GHPages need at least one file named index.html (that will be your homepage). Try some tests with static pages and redirecting  to understand the behaviour of GHPages.

Comment: Follow these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77735145/17627866) which utilize a github action to deploy any folder of your choice to github pages